# C- possible memory leak?

Tags: c, data-structures, multidimensional-array, struct, free

I feel that a piece of code I have would cause a memory leak. I have a data structure with two two-dimensional arrays, one containing ints and one containing pointers to dynamically-allocated objects (sprites). The data structure is a tilemap, and the ints are the numeric index of each location, which are read from a file. I call that index 'tiles'. This tells what kind of tile it is, for behavioral purposes (i.e. player responds differently to water than to dirt or ice). The objects are the sprites to draw at their respective locations. That index is known as 'images'. That index tells the tilemap what sprite to draw at that position.

```
typedef struct
{
    int** tiles;
    sprite*** images;
    int w, h;
} tilemap;
```

I have a function that creates a new tilemap, initializes it, and returns it.

```
tilemap* new_tilemap(int w, int h, const char* filename)
{
    tilemap* tm = malloc(sizeof(tilemap));
    tm->w = w;
    tm->h = h;

    /*allocate memory space for the tiles index*/
    tm->tiles = malloc(sizeof(int) * h);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < h; ++i)
    {
        tm->tiles[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * w);
    }

    /*fill the index with the appropriate data from a file*/
    FILE* file = fopen (filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open map %s\n", filename);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < h; ++j)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < w; ++i)
        {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &(tm->tiles[j][i]));
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    /*allocate space for the images*/
    tm->images = malloc(sizeof(sprite*) * h);
    for (i = 0; i < h; ++i)
    {
        tm->images[i] = malloc(sizeof(sprite*) * w);
    }

    /*load images based on what type of tile is at that position*/
    for (j = 0; j < h; ++j)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < w; ++i)
        {
            switch (tm->tiles[j][i])
            {
                case 0:
                tm->images[j][i] = new_sprite_file("dat/tiles/0.bmp", 1);
                break;
                case 1:
                tm->images[j][i] = new_sprite_file("dat/tiles/1.bmp", 2);
                break;
            }
            tm->images[j][i]->x = i*tm->images[j][i]->w;
            tm->images[j][i]->y = j*tm->images[j][i]->h;
        }
    }
    return tm;
}
```

Then, to free the tilemap and all it's structures I have this function:

```
void free_tilemap(tilemap* tm)
{
    /*loop through and free each of the images in the array*/
    int i, j;
    for (j = 0; j < tm->h; ++j)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < tm->w; ++i)
        {
            free(tm->images[j][i]);
         }
    }
    /*free the actual array*/
    free(tm->images);
    /*free the tile array?*/
    free(tm->tiles);
    /*free the entire tilemap structure*/
    free(tm);
}
```

However, I feel that it isn't freeing up all the memory I have allocated, because I used malloc twice on the tiles, but only free'd once. I don't know if this is a problem though, seeing as they are ints, but I think that I may have to loop through the tiles array, free every row, then loop through and free every column (containing the rows), in the same manner as it was allocated. Is that what needs to be done or am I just being ignorant and/or paranoid? The same with the images array. Also, feel free to point out other flaws in my code as I know I'm not the best programmer.

Comment: Some of your malloc types are wrong. `tiles` should be `malloc(sizeof(int*) * N)`, and `images` should be `malloc(sizeof(sprite**) * M)`, etc.

Comment: Have You considered using a memory profiling tool like valgrind on linux or purify on windows?

Comment: @Keelx: To allocate memory for `N` elements of type `T`, you say `T * p = malloc(sizeof(T) * N);`. Now apply this logic to the cases` T = int*` and `T = sprite**` in the respective situations. And don't forget to `free()` everything you allocate. I daresay if you're not totally at home with those ideas, the feeling of "being more productive with C" is probably a misleading sensation...

Comment: @KerrekSB Okay I understand what you're saying. Making the changes, valgrind shows no change in the amount of memory in use at exit, compared to the program without your suggested changes.

Comment: @Keelx: Almost guaranteed you're forgetting to clean something up. You can use valgrind to show where the reachable memory was allocated to get an idea.

Comment: @KerrekSB Found them all now. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you should mirror the `malloc`s when you free.

```
for (i = 0; i < h; ++i)
{
    tm->tiles[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * w);
}

/* Inside free_tilemap. */
for (i = 0; i < h; ++i)
{
    free(tm->tiles[i]);
}
free(tm->tiles);
```

Same goes for the other `for`s that closely resemble this one. Freeing just `tiles` doesn't automatically free `tiles[0..h]` in cascade.

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation, too. What about the images array though?

Comment: @Keelx `tm->images[i] = malloc(sizeof(sprite*) * w)` makes me think of `free(tm->images[i])`.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code quickly I would say that you are indeed missing the free's on the tiles. I would suggest to use a memory analyzer to find out for yourself. E.g. http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html
That will give you a good overview of allocated memory, and possible memory leaks when the program exits.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to be a very useful tool for things like this.